# Random segfault When using global 2d variable instead of local one

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, global-variables

this is the half-done code that I should convert to a multithread one.
I need to read from the global 2d double variable "vector" in all my threads.
so I converted it from local var in main to a global one (as you see I commented the old one in line 33) suddenly after only this one change my code started to give random but often segfaults I changed it back to local and ran the code 1000 times and not one time it broke but changing this one local 2d var to global will ruins everything
I really don't know what to do please help me.

```
# include <stdio.h> 
# include <string.h> 
# include <pthread.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <math.h>

# define NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS 20
# define NUMBER_OF_CLASSES 4
# define NUMBER_OF_THREADS 4
# define NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS_PLUS_ONE 21 //STUPID C WONT LET ME MAKE GLOBAL VECTORS
    double vectors[NUMBER_OF_CLASSES][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS_PLUS_ONE];

double max[NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS], min[NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
pthread_t threads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
void * solve(void *id){
    FILE *traincsv;
    long tid;
    tid = (long) id;
    char buffer[1024];
    char* token;
    int EOFchecker = 1;
    printf("Hello World! Thread ID, %ld\n", tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main(){
    FILE *traincsv, *traincsvnorm, *weightscsv;
    char buffer[1024];
    char* token;
    double temp;
    // double max[NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS], min[NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
    int EOFchecker = 1;
    int number_of_datas = 0, number_of_wrong_predictions = 0;
    // double vectors[NUMBER_OF_CLASSES][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS + 1];
    double sum[NUMBER_OF_CLASSES];
    int winner;
    int return_code;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; i++)
    {
        min[i] = INFINITY;
    }
    
    
    traincsv = fopen("train.csv","r");
    traincsvnorm = fopen("trainnorm.csv","w+");
    weightscsv = fopen("weights.csv","r");
    // fprintf(traincsvnorm,"%s\n",buffer);
    //load vectors to array last one is bias
    fscanf(weightscsv,"%s",buffer);//first junk line
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CLASSES; i++)
    {
        fscanf(weightscsv,"%s",buffer);
        token = strtok(buffer,",");
        for (size_t j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS + 1; j++)
        {
            temp = atof(token);
            vectors[i][j] = temp;
            token = strtok(NULL,",");//next token of last string
        }
    }
    //find min and max
    fscanf(traincsv,"%s",buffer);//first line is just names
    fscanf(traincsv,"%s",buffer);
    while (EOFchecker != EOF)
    {
        token = strtok(buffer,",");
        for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; i++)
        {
            temp = atof(token);
            if(max[i]<temp) max[i] = temp;
            if(min[i]>temp) min[i] = temp;
            token = strtok(NULL,",");//next token of last string
        }
        EOFchecker = fscanf(traincsv,"%s",buffer);
    }
    // Normilize
    double maxMinusMin[NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; i++)
    {
        maxMinusMin[i] = max[i] - min[i];
    }
    EOFchecker = 1;
    fseek(traincsv,0,SEEK_SET);
    fscanf(traincsv,"%s",buffer);//first line is just names
    fscanf(traincsv,"%s",buffer);
    while (EOFchecker != EOF)
    {
        token = strtok(buffer,",");
        //reset sum of wieghts to bias;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CLASSES; i++)
        {
            sum[i] = vectors[i][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; i++)
        {
            temp = atof(token);
            temp = (temp-min[i])/(maxMinusMin[i]);
            for (size_t j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_CLASSES; j++)
            {
                sum[j] += vectors[j][i] * temp;
            }
            token = strtok(NULL,",");//next token of last string
        }
        //check which vector has most points
        for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CLASSES; i++)
        {
            if (sum[i] > sum[winner])
            {
                winner = i;
            }
            
        }
        if(winner != atof(token)){
            number_of_wrong_predictions ++;
        }
        number_of_datas ++;
        EOFchecker = fscanf(traincsv,"%s",buffer);
    }
    // for(long tid = 0; tid < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; tid++)
    // {
    //     printf("%ld\n",tid);
    //  return_code = pthread_create(&threads[tid],
    //          NULL, solve, (void *) tid);

    //  if (return_code)
    //  {
    //      printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n",
    //              return_code);
    //      exit(-1);
    //  }
    // }

    printf("wrong predictions : %d \nall predictions : %d \n",number_of_wrong_predictions,number_of_datas);
    fclose(traincsv);
    fclose(traincsvnorm);
    fclose(weightscsv);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

and these are the inputs
[train.csv](https://pastebin.com/0TLD1ke9)
[weights.csv](https://pastebin.com/AMq79DVf)

Comment: Hi Asha! There is nothing wrong with global variable initialization in C :)
You forgot to initialize the "winner" variable; therefore, the program will access an element of memory that is not for itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable winner is not initialized when used the first time so,
if (sum[i] > sum[winner])
might access a field way outside of sum and cause a seg fault.

When the vector array is on the stack, winner has probably a smaller random value and causes no seg fault.

Comment: yes, it fixed the problem :|. I really thought it has sth to do with vectors array. it is still strange though why changing that variable to global causes the winner to be much higher value

Comment: Changing the array variable from local to global moves it from the stack to the bss section, therefore "winner" probably get a different offset on the stack and a different random value. The "working" version with the local arrays was just lucky.